# Ubuntu installed on HDD does not see SSD with Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I bought a windows laptop that uses 128GB SSD + 1TB HDD.
Windows was pre-installed on the SSD.
I installed Ubuntu on the HDD.

But the GRUB boot loader does not appear and the laptop automatically boots into Ubuntu.
To access Windows, I have to press <kbd>F12</kbd> while the laptop on to use the UEFI boot loader.

How can I get GRUB working so the [option to boot into Windows](https://images.app.goo.gl/t35HqYHkwK6EDySv9) appears without having to press <kbd>F12</kbd>every time I start my laptop?

I also noticed that while installing Ubuntu, the option to `install ubuntu alongside windows` did not appear and I had to use the `something else` option to manually partition the disk.

Edit 1: Result of `sudo grub-update`

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-13-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Edit 2: When I used Boot Repair, Recommended repair, GRUB showed up without Windows. I think Ubuntu can’t detect windows.

[image: Image of Grub]

Edit 3: [Boot Repair Summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NTF7H3shcj/)

Comment: Boot into ubuntu and type sudo update-grub,then post a screenshot of the output. That way we can see if windows gets detected at all by grub.

Comment: Also, you didn't see the "install alongside windows" because on the HDD was no operating system, therefore the installer did not suggest you this option

Comment: The "install alongside windows" problem could also be because your windows partition don't precise that it's windows

Comment: The previous hypothesis are likely wrong. What is likely to have happened is you installing Ubuntu in Legacy mode.

Comment: But in your "grub image" **Windows** is shown. What happens when you select it? Please [edit] the question to answer this, not in comments (you may also leave a comment to me, preceded by @ and my username when done).

Comment: @bogdanpetru I made an edit with the desired text

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I meant to say that is the desired grub image

Comment: Better to see details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Use the 2nd option in a live session, do not make changes, just get the report and post the link here. Menwhile, can you find the Windows boot entry in UEFi?

Comment: Yes Windows is available in UEFI

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia an error occurs during the repair when I use recommended repair.
The log file is huge and wouldn't fit here

Comment: I told not to repair, just get the report. If you have Internet connection ot should automatically upload to a pasty service and show a link which is what I asked in the previous comment.

Comment: Now GRUB shows up but it does does not have a windows option

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'm a little confused what I was supposed to do.
I just opened boot repair and hit recommended repair.
There was no link provided.

Comment: There are TWO buttons, one says "create a bootinfo summary". That's the report we need to try to understand what's happening.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia is this after I hit recommended repair?
Sorry Im new to this

Comment: No, INSTEAD of.

Comment: Done: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NTF7H3shcj/
@GabrielaGarcia

Comment: Thanks, that's it but please edit it in the question. Now, the problem: Ubuntu isn't "seeing" the drive where Windows is installed. You may need to check SATA mode or similar settings on UEFI (the new name for BIOS). RAID or INTEL RST modes aren't supported, only AHCI (preferable) or IDE.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia so I should switch to AHCI drivers?
What should I do after that to complete the fix?

Comment: Please be aware that if you don't have AHCI drivers installed in Windows it may not boot after changing to that mode but is always possible to revert it, install and change again. Not sure if that's the problem but usually is. The fact is Ubuntu isn't seeing the other drive and consequently it can't add Windows to the Grub menu.

Comment: I changed to ACHI, hit boot repair and switched back to RAID.
It works now.
Thanks @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: @Soham Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [don’t add “SOLVED” to the title](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/250300). If you solved your problem, post an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: @Soham I posted your solution as a community-answer. Feel free to repost it using your profile to get the relevant reputation and then [let me know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), so I can remove my answer.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer was originally posted by the asker as an [edit to the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1136039/7) and [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136039/ubuntu-installed-on-hdd-does-not-see-ssd-with-windows/1142840?noredirect=1#comment1883686_1136039).*

Switch to AHCI, run boot-repair and switch back to RAID.

Comment: After switching to `AHCI`, OP ran `boot-repair` then switched back to `RAID`. At least that's the way I read the comment...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You are right, I forgot about that comment when I created this answer. It‘s updated now, please check it and feel free to edit.

Comment: Looks good to me and I upvoted. Thanks.